# How to arrange by a column ( each data frame has different number) a list of dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames want to `arrange desc` by third column. But the third column names not the same names. example: in data frame one column name is 1, data frame two column name is 2 and so on.
this is the third data frame of list:

```
 head(third)
  PROVINCE DISTRICT       10
1       11        1   677.17
2       11        3   115.69
3       11        4 21119.15
4       11        5 12580.12
5       11        6 90743.17
6       11        8   171.84
```

Comment: `df[, 3]` would select the third column in a data frame regardless of its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have list of dataframe in `list_df`, you may use `lapply` with `order`.

In base R,

```
list_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) x[order(-x[[3]]), ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
third %>%
  arrange(desc(.[,3]))

  PROVINCE DISTRICT    X10
     <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1       11        6 90743.
2       11        4 21119.
3       11        5 12580.
4       11        1   677.
5       11        8   172.
6       11        3   116.
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use `arrange` with column index, use `across`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list_df <- map(list_df, ~ .x %>%
                    arrange(across(3, desc)))
```